# Disable all Emacs c-mode reformatting, insertion/refusal, cursor jumps

Tags: c, emacs, cursor-position, autoformatting

I want to keep all syntax highlighting, autocomplete, commands etc. of Emacs c-mode (and I'll add in company-mode or similar shortly) but I want to disable everything in c-mode which:

1. Reformats other than if I C-*<command>* or M-*<command>* ask it to.
2. Moves my cursor around the source, even momentarily, unless I asked for it. For example, closing parens/braces highlighting the matching one.
3. Ever i) inserts anything I didn't type (other than 1 Tab = 4 spaces) or ii) refuses to insert something I did type because formatting.
4. Reformats, repaginates, realigns or otherwise edits the source for any reason, including on paste, on save, or because the moon is gibbous.

I've already set `(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)` and `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`.

I have tried:

- `C-x C-l` a.k.a. `c-toggle-electric-state` a.k.a. `(setq-default c-electric-flag nil)` which fixes some of 4, but Tab still reformats code when it feels inclined, and I'm guessing isn't alone; and doesn't fix 2 or 3.
- `c-auto-align-backslashes` which fixes one above case only.
- `(setq c-syntactic-indentation nil)` which partially fixes 4, but breaks 1 and 3 (for instance, Tab doesn't insert at the cursor), and doesn't fix 2.
- `text-mode` which obviously removes all the c-mode features I want to keep.
- Various searches and dives into https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html, which carefully documents 2^1024 settings but doesn't exhibit an "all formatting off" switch that I can find.
- Scanning https://sourceforge.net/p/cc-mode/cc-mode/ci/default/tree/ for obvious flags to disable (*blork*?)

I've been at this for hours, so any help gratefully received.

*Update:* More thrashing around: installing emacs source code (`apt-get install emacs24-el`) and using `C-h k <key combo>` to find the function called when a key is pressed. `M-x find-function` to browse that source to work out what it's actually doing and look for hooks. `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` to stick with spaces, not tabs. `(setq-default blink-matching-paren nil)` to prevent cursor jump on closing parens/braces. I still can't disable formatting, or achieve 1, 2, 3 and 4, but I'm getting better at whack-a-mole.

Comment: This is a pretty involved process to get everything right.  You really need an emacs wizard very familiar with C mode.  You might be able to get a better answer on the [emacs SE site](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Type `M-x describe-mode` and you will see a `*Help*` buffer that contains (in part) all of the key bindings that are active.  Much of the behavior that you wish to avoid, I suspect, are particular functions being activated when you simply wish to insert a particular character on the keyboard.  You can disable each and every function assigned to particular keys if you do not like the behavior.  You can also type `M-x describe-key` and press a key to see if it is just inserting a character from the keyboard or calling a special function that contains behavior that does not appeal to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observation: this is a difficult sort of question to answer, because "disable everything that does ...." is a bit unspecific.  However...

Item 2.  (Moving point momentarily to the matching open paren when you type a close paren) is easy: (setq blink-matching-paren nil).  This is in the Emacs manual on page "Matching Parentheses".  (Whoops! You've already found that one).

You don't like the action of the tab key; what do you want it to do?  It's bound to c-indent-command, which indents the current line inwards or outwards to the "correct" position.  I'm guessing you want  simply to insert spaces to bring point to the next 4*nth position.  How about tab-to-tab-stop?  Try (define-key c-mode-base-map "\t" 'tab-to-tab-stop).  Note that defining it in the default key map would not work, since the major mode key map takes priority over it.

Having done C-c C-l to disable the automatic indentation on typing, e.g., a ;, does typing a ; still do anything to offend?  If so, you could disable its "special" features entirely with (define-key c-mode-base-map ";" 'self-insert-command)

Again, a list of specific things you don't like, even a long list, is a lot easier to deal with than "everything which inserts anything I didn't type".  The maintainer of the mode just doesn't mentally classify things that way.

Anyhow, I hope you manage to get things sorted out.

Comment: "The maintainer of the mode just doesn't mentally classify things that way." That's the key point for me, thanks. The more I use Emacs, the more I find  modes are set up as "here are n highly granular features with default settings, and at least n 'settings' you can tweak if you don't like them". Seems there are few modes with broad "I understand you may not want code formatting, no problem" off switches. With similar point-hacks I've been disabling the functionality that seriously bugs me, and will just have to play hide and seek when something else happens.